# Searching entry for specific characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wish for the invisible label to show as green should the "@" symbol, however it doesn't not do this and just does nothing. I wish for this to then move on to the next function, something I can do myself. I can change this so that the label appears if the "@" symbol is not in the string but then it does not accept it when the @ symbol is actually in the string.

```
from tkinter import *

class Traveller:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.E_email = "sd"
        self.go = Frame(parent, width=500, height=450, bg="snow", pady=30, padx=10)
        self.go.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.go.grid_propagate(0)  # to reserve space required for frame

        email = Label(self.go, text="Email:", bg="snow")
        email.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.E_email = Entry(self.go, width=40)
        self.E_email.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

        menuButton = Button(self.go, text="Continue", command=self.dataCheck)
        menuButton.grid(row=8, column=1, pady=8)

        self.meme = Label(self.go, text = "", bg = "snow")
        self.meme.grid(row=9, column=0, columnspan = 3)

    def dataCheck(self):
        self.E_email = str(self.E_email)
        if "@" in self.E_email:
            self.meme.configure(text="memem", bg = "olive drab")           

# main routine
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Traveller Details")
    play = Traveller(root)
    root.geometry("500x450+0+0")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you mean use `self.E_email` here? `self.E_email.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)`

Comment: I suggest you add `print(self.E_email` right after setting it in `dataCheck`, to see if it is what you think it is (hint: it's not).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `self.E_mail.get()` to get the text inside of the entry widget.

```
if "@" in self.E_mail.get():
     ...
```